# How to show or hide button on one specific checkbox on JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a problem when using checkbox with JQuery. I want to show the button when user check only in draft_checkbox. I try with ***draft*** checkbox click. But, it can only show/hide in draft checkbox. When I click other checkbox, it still showing. I just want to show button when user check on draft checkbox only. If user check both, I want to hide.

Here my script,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {                
           $('#draft').click(function () {
                if($("#draft").is(':checked')){
                    $('#btnApprovepo').css('visibility','visible');                    
                }else{
                    $('#btnApprovepo').css('visibility','hidden');                                             
                }
            });
        });
</script> 

<div id="status_div">
    <input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="draft" value="d" checked="checked"/> Draft<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="pending" value="n" /> Pending <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="submit" value="s" /> Submitted <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="pAck" value="c" /> Partial Ack <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="ack" value="a" /> Acknowledged <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="partial" value="p" /> Partial Delivered <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="delivered" value="e" /> Delivered <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="void" value="v" /> Void <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="reject" value="r" /> Reject <br />
</div>
```

Here my button,

```
<input type='button' value='Button' name='Button' id='btnApprovepo' />
```

Comment: Though w3schools is not extremely reliable source, [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) they got it right. You can use JQuery's `hide()` and `show()` methods.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Het8/

Comment: K-THIHA, users expect to be able to click the text next to the checkbox. This is easily fixed by wrapping it and the text with label: `<label><input type="checkbox" class="po_status" name="status" id="reject" value="r" /> Reject</label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/XqXL9/2/**

```
$('.po_status').click(function () {
    if($(".po_status:checked").length === 1 && $("#draft").is(":checked") == true){
         $('#btnApprovepo').show();
    } else {
         $('#btnApprovepo').hide(); 
    }
});
```

**some best pratices:**

1. use triple === for exact comparison.
2. use classes if we have it, instead of the tags for matching.
3. visibility just makes it invisible but occupies the space. `Is that what you need?`.
4. enclose code between braces even if it is a single line code

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/zCkKc/

```
$(document).ready(function() {                
    $('#status_div input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        if($("#status_div :checked").length == 1 && $("#draft").is(":checked") == true)
            $('#btnApprovepo').show();
        else
            $('#btnApprovepo').hide()
    });
});
```

I dont know why have used `visibility` css. may be for requirement. but i recommend you to use `.show()` and `.hide()` to toggle visibility.

Comment: can you add a working fiddle to complete your answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote but you've changed the formatting of the if/else. You really shouldn't alter someone's formatting just because you prefer it, especially when they require help.

Comment: Why i am getting downvote guys? we are here to help people and instead of appreciation we are getting downvotes

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way...
Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/abhinandanAryal/V7ZT2/1/)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#draft").click(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $('#btnApprovepo').css("visibility","visible");
            }
            else
            {
                $('#btnApprovepo').css("visibility","hidden");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you post an answer you should check that it works. Questions that have answers may be skipped by SO users who could provide help. By posting an answer that doesn't work you may be depriving someone of useful advice and working code.